# extract the first character from stringset

Tags: r

I have this annotation list of chromosome number. I would to extract the first character from each string

```
[[1]]
[1] "KQ415812.1"

[[2]]
 [1] "KQ415813.1" "KQ415813.1" "KQ415813.1" "KQ415813.1" "KQ415813.1" "KQ415813.1" "KQ415813.1" 
[12] "KQ415813.1" "KQ415813.1" "KQ415813.1" "KQ415813.1" "KQ415813.1" "KQ415813.1" "KQ415813.1" 


[[3]]
 [1] "KQ415814.1" "KQ415814.1" "KQ415814.1" "KQ415814.1" "KQ415814.1" "KQ415813.1"
[12] "KQ415814.1"
```

I would have this result because the character in each string are repeated so i need to show them only one time

```
[[1]]
[1] "KQ415812.1"

[[2]]
 [1] "KQ415813.1" 
[12] "KQ415813.1" 

[[3]]
 [1] "DKQ415814.1"
 [12] "DKQ415814.1"
```

Any helps? thank you

Comment: In the third vector of your list there are two different elements: `"KQ415814.1"` and `"KQ415813.1"`. You might look for unique elements here `lapply(your_list, unique)` ?!

Comment: I did it. thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loop through the `list` (`lapply`), create a logical expression to get the first element

```
lapply(lst1, function(x) x[!duplicated(x)])
```

Answer (score 1):

`purrr` solution:

```
library(purrr)

yours_list %>%
  map(~.x[1])
```